# Responsive design not working on Android?

Tags: android, css, responsive-design

I'm testing on both Nexus 4 - 4.1.1 - 768x1280 and Xperia Z - 4.2.2 - 1080x1920...  In both cases, my site (which is responsive on desktops) is only partially responsive in android phones.  WP8 works fine (surprisingly) - and iPhone 5 works - except the height is a little more than it should be (sticky footer isn't showing up).  It's as if the CSS thinks there's an extra 100px or so - things are just slightly cut off when they shouldn't be.  An example media query:

```
/* if device is less than 768px */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container{
        width: auto;
        max-width: calc(100% ~"-" 20px);
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .banner-info{
        padding-right: 15px;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 300px;
        font-size: 13px !important;
    }

}
```

In my header:

```
<meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

What's going on here?

Comment: what if you try `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { ... }` instead?

Comment: @beworker trying now..

Comment: @beworker - that didn't work... I also replaced the semicolons with commas and it didn't work.  No errors, just incorrect sizing.

Comment: wtf is `100% ~"-" 20px` expression in calc? `100% - 20px` works fine.

Comment: How wide does javascript believe the window is?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `target-densityDpi=device-dpi` to your `meta viewport`. It's an `Android` specific value.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
```

UPDATE:

I recently found out that `target-densityDpi` is no longer supported. I solved a similar problem by combining `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` with `max-width` while also not using `target-densityDpi` in my `meta viewport`:

```
    @media  all and (max-width:360px),
            screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3.0) and (max-width: 1080px),
            screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0) and (max-width: 720px) {
        // CSS HERE
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

The version on Android you are using does not support `calc` and you must provide a fallback.  I suggest something like this:

```
width: 90%; /* fallback */
width: calc(100% - 20px);
```

But now your pixel-based margin is not going to result in a centered layout.  At that point, I suggest you just forget the "calc" altogether and use plain 'ol css:

```
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted, you're absolutely right that calc does not work prior to Android 4.4/KitKat with the stock browser and in web views.

Answer (score 0):

Adroid phone like the nexus or Galaxy serie have a "retina desplay" mening the pixel ratio is 2 so you have to add this (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)

so

`@media (max-width: 768px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)`

Comment: This tool should help find the exqct query per device http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html

Comment: I just tried this - responsiveness on my desktop stops working, so this isn't an option.  Unless you're saying I need duplicate queries, one for desktop and one for android?  I hope not...

Comment: I actually made a mistake you have to divide the number of pixel by the pixel ratio check with your phone for the exact number of the max width  and the pixel ratio there [link]pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html[link]

Comment: I don't know Why I got linus one but this works @media (max-width: 384px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in header

```
<meta name="viewport"
content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

it worked for me

Comment: I'm not going to down vote, but disabling zoom should not be a part of your boilerplate or copy/paste toolbox.  You should only disable zoom **deliberately** when you are **absolutely sure** your users will never **want** to zoom.  (I say "want" b/c it's very different from what you think users "need").